# How can I find an element or his index in a list by a few characters of it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

How can I find an element or his index in a list by a few characters of it?

For Example:

```
x = input()
list = ['alberto', 'kari', 'mino']

#now I want to find the element, which starts or contain x (for exampke x = 'albe')
#the next similir element should be found
#and then remove it
```

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: @MikeScotty this is not a homework. this is for my discord music bot. I am looking for a more effective way to remove elements of my song-queue-list :)

Comment: In that case: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) The point is still the same: your question shows zero effort to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: @MikeScotty Okay I do understand the point of yours, I will think twice about it next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for item in list:
      If 'alb' in item:
          Item.pop()
```